# Creating an index with Elasticsearch 5.0 throws a Bad Request exception

Tags: php, elasticsearch, zend-framework

I use Elasticsearch 2.4 and I decided to test my code with Elasticsearch 5.0.

So, I installed Elasticsearch 5.0, started it and then tried to use my PHP function that creates an index and populates it.

But I get this error :

```
 Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\BadRequest400Exception
 No handler found for uri [/devmaestro_fr_articles] and method [POST]
```

And this one :

```
 Guzzle\Http\Exception\ClientErrorResponseException
 Client error response
[status code] 400
[reason phrase] Bad Request
[url] http://localhost:9200/devmaestro_fr_articles
```

If I use the same PHP function with Elasticsearch 2.4, it works fine.
So, do you have any idea about this problem? Is the way to create an index into Elasticsearch 5.0 different than Elasticsearch 2.4?

I'm developing a web app based on Zend Framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It used to be possible to create an index using either POST or PUT, but since [the Pull Request #20001](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/20001), it is not possible anymore to use POST and only PUT is allowed.

So you simply need to change POST with PUT in your code and it should work.

Comment: Thank you, i'll test it.

Moreover, i've seen that we can't use "string" type for mapping, now we have to use "text" type. I think it'll be really complicated to update to elastic 5.0.

Hurry up, i'm trying it on dev environnement.

Comment: Yes, indeed, you need to also change "string+analyzed" to "text" and "string+not_analyzed" to "keyword". But you can also let it that way and ES will happily make the conversions itself.

Comment: " ES will happily make the conversions itself" => good, i'll not have to do this.
With my collegues, we do not now if it's really relevant to up our ES. What do u think about that ?

Comment: Before upgrading, you should go through the [breaking changes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_50_mapping_changes.html#_literal_string_literal_fields_replaced_by_literal_text_literal_literal_keyword_literal_fields) as this might not be the only thing that impacts you. ES5 was a huge non-backward compatible release.

Comment: Yes, i'm developing with Zend Framework 2.2 ans we'll up to v3.0
Do you know if a elastic module exists for Zend Framework 3.0 ?

Comment: I'm not using Zend, but Google spits out [a few things](https://www.google.ch/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=zend%20elasticsearch)

Comment: I know but it's seems there are not results for zend framework 3.0 so i asked it here in case anyone know.